# How to get no of lines in a MS word file(.doc) using a java program

Tags: java

By using Apache POI I am able to get data from MS Word documents but the problem here is, the Word file is read as paragraphs. So each paragraph is read as single line. My java code line count doesn't match with the line count given by .doc file. Can anyone suggest me how to get line-count using Apache POI or any alternative ways.

Comment: Can you show us what code you've used so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following way may be preferable for you

```
        DocumentSummaryInformation summaryInfo=doc.getDocumentSummaryInformation();
        String category = summaryInfo.getCategory();
        String company = summaryInfo.getCompany();
        int lineCount=summaryInfo.getLineCount();
```

refer [java-and-docx-format](http://sanjaal.com/java/tag/java-and-docx-format/)

Comment: MS word line_count gives me 71 but using above summaryInfo.getLineCount() gives count=24;

Comment: my mail_is:mahesh.penmatsa@gmail.com add me so i can send u my .doc file